# Why does 1 + 1 ? 1 : 0 + 1 return 1 instead of 3?

Tags: javascript

Why is `1 + 1 ? 1 : 0 + 1` equal to `1` and not `3`? It's correct that it returns 3 if I wrap the expression `1 ? 1 : 0` with parentheses. But why is that needed? What is actually blocking the process to parse it correctly?

Comment: Research: operator precedence.

Comment: Thank you @jonrsharpe. I will read more about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Because** js first calculate 1 + 1 and after that check RESULT is true? if it is true, select **1**.

> 1+1 is the truthy result

> **The falsy values in JavaScript are 0, 0n, null, undefined, false, NaN, and the empty string ""**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is evaluating (1 + 1) ? 1 : (0 + 1).

Comment: Please refrain from answering questions which have obviously been asked before.